# UX Strategy Document

Tags: strategy

Does anyone have an example of a UX Strategy document please?

I'm currently attempting to put together a UX strategy. I'm reviewing customer feedback, conducting stakeholder interviews etc but not sure how to present my suggestions/UX activities.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is something you'll need to create on your own since it's your own branding, it's the way you present yourself. Whether you choose to be creative, hip, classic, conservative or whatever.

Once you have decided how to present it (and believe me, it's the most important part), it will depend on the project, since not all projects are the same and only you know the client, the product, the budget and all other details.

About what to include, take a look to **[Guide Your Design With a 1-Page UX Strategy](https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/guide-your-design-with-a-1-page-ux-strategy/)**. Please note that **I don't recommend to do this all in one page**, but the elements the article mentions are pretty much spot on. To summarize, the article mentions:

- Vision
- Circumstances of Use
- Design Criteria
- Success Metrics (*take what the article says with a grain of salt, please!*)

Or, if you want to be more "classic" (this is taken from a project we did for a very conservative company):

- Present Yourself
- Explain how will you help them (a simple 1 or 2 paragraphs explanation is more than enough)
- Explain what kind of results may they expect
- Explain what tools are you going to use. For example, you may consider a whole **[Design Thinking](https://www.ideou.com/pages/design-thinking)** process and everything that it involves. Here you also add timelines and you may need to add some costs (for example, if you need to rent facilities for testing). See an [example of things](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/03/creating-a-ux-strategy/) to consider right under the "Design Touchpoints" title
- Explain how much will this cost, and if possible, how much time will it take to recover the investment

***Tip:*** Include as many visual examples as possible. Since you won't have examples for them, you should use from your previous work, from their competition or articles that are pertinent to the project.

As for visual presentation: again, it's your choice, but the least you must do is to *"brand the presentation"* and deliver in a **non-editable** PDF. Include a cover and an end page, think of this as a small book that will provide information as well as delight the user. They want and NEED to see you're all over the game

## Additional Documentation

- [How to Develop an Actionable UX Product Roadmap](https://medium.com/@denisz.design/how-to-develop-an-actionable-ux-product-roadmap-fcb341632833)
- [How to Create an Enterprise UX Strategy](https://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2016/12/how-to-create-an-enterprise-ux-strategy.php)
- [Oracle Applications Cloud User Experience Strategy & Roadmap (PDF)](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/cloud-ux-strategy-ebook-2967646.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

To me, it is a bit unclear what you need. Do you have to present some look and feel for an application to your boss or customer? Are there superior corporate UX strategy documents that need to be considered? Do you have to present some flow of screens?

Maybe you don't really mean "strategy", as strategy describes basic and long term decisions that are guides for more detailed decisions. To me, your question sounds more like you need some UX style guide that also consists the reasoning (interview evaluation).

UX style guides usually contains at least of:

- the color palette
- the main layouts and widget layouts
- fonts and font sizes
- paragraphs, lists, ...
- visuals control elements (like "button, active, hovering" ...)
- flow of screens

dealing with workstation, tablet, phone size.

If you create such a guide for yourself, it is useful because every new feature you implement, you can consult your style guide and design the feature so that it matches smoothly to the rest of the application (visual consistency). In companies, on the other hand, usually UX design documents are often expensive collections of documents. You have better chances to find something in the internet by search. Search by "UX style guide examples".

Here style guide examples:

- http://hugeinc.github.io/styleguide/demo/index.html#!colors
- https://www.toptal.com/designers/ui/ui-styleguide-better-ux
- https://bashooka.com/inspiration/40-great-examples-of-ui-style-guides/

They all show you the same foundation that will help to make your application consistent, and that are a valuable discussion base for your superiors.

For completeness, here is also an example of a strategic document.

https://de.slideshare.net/Kalbach/ux-strategy-blueprint